# Babel.config.js only for jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

we are using jest on a react typescript project. If there is a babel.config.js with preset: [@babel/preset-env] the test running successfully.
But with the existence of that babel file our next.js web project is not compiling any more.

How can I setup this babel.config.js only for jest and not for next.js?

Comment: [Check this out](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#:~:text=Making%20your%20Babel%20config%20jest%2Daware)

Answer (score 12):

An alternate solution to [@slideshowp2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71290964/3136861) is to have a separate babelrc file dedicated to jest only.

For example, you can call it `babel.config.testing.js` then in your `jest.config.js` file, you tell jest to use this dedicated babelrc file:

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '\\.js$': ['babel-jest', { configFile: './Configuration/babel.config.testing.js' }]
  },

};
```

Ref: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3845#issuecomment-645298425

Comment: Thanks! This solution seems to actually allow to use babel only with jest contrary to the test environment method. It worked for me when trying to solve an issue on a Next.js app when the other one stilled disabled SWC and made compiling the app impossible

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I suddenly needed this going from v26 -> v29, including the `configFIle` even though mine has a standard `babel.config.js` name :/

Answer (score 4):

See [Making your Babel config jest-aware](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-babel)

> Jest will set process.env.NODE_ENV to 'test' if it's not set to something else. You can use that in your configuration to conditionally setup only the compilation needed for Jest, e.g.

`babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = api => {
  const isTest = api.env('test');
  // You can use isTest to determine what presets and plugins to use.

  return {
    // ...
  };
};
```